# Transition matrix between bases for polynomial vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, transition-matrix

Consider the bases $b=(p_1, p_2)$ and $b' = (q_1, q_2)$ for $p_1$, where $p_1 = 6 + 3x$, $p_2 = 10 + 2x$, $q_1 = 10 + 2x$, $q_1 = 2$, $q_2 = 3 + 2x$. Find the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$.

I've seen some others answer to similar questions online, but I really have no idea why they are doing certain steps. All I understand is to write $B$ in terms of $B'$ as a linear combination like $p_1 = q_1 + q_2 \implies 6 + 3x = 2 + 3 + 2x$.

I just really have no idea how to solve this type of problem. I can do it without the values being equations but how would you do it when the values are equations?

Comment: You wrote both $q_1=10+2x$ and $q_1=2$.

Comment: Polynomials are not "equations".  Why not use $p_1=\frac94 q_1+ \frac32 q_2$, $p_2= \dots$.

Comment: The first step in solving any problem is to make sure you have not misread the problem or copied the problem incorrectly. In your case, you need to carefully review the statement of the problem and determine whether $q_1$ is supposed to be equal to $2, 10+2x$, or something else. In addition, you should probably review the definition of transition matrix.